CSS selectors, target an empty span but not span that has an <a> tag or tags in it
I have these two markup up patterns:
<h3>
    <span>Title</span>
    <span></span>
</h3>

and
<h3>
    <span>Title</span>
    <span><a>link</a><a>link</a></span>
</h3>

I want to target the former but not the latter with CSS and use ::after to insert a visual flourish. I prefer not to use a class. I just can't seem to get it!
h3>span+span:not(h3>span+span>a)::after {
    border: solid 1px transparent;
    content: '\2199';
    display: inline-block;
    color: gray;
}


Use :not(:has(*)) to select an empty element (more detail from my blog: https://css-tip.com/number-elements-has-selector/)


h3 span:last-child:not(:has(*))::after {
  border: solid 1px transparent;
  content: '\2199';
  display: inline-block;
  color: gray;
}
<h3>
  <span>Title</span>
  <span></span>
</h3>
and

<h3>
  <span>Title</span>
  <span><a>link</a><a>link</a></span>
</h3>




Thanks, Temani! That's perfect, and love the 'How Many Elements Your Container Has?' write up.

You could also just use the :empty pseudo-selector. :has() has great browser support now, so I wouldn't stress too much about browser compatibility nowdays, so that's for you to decide.
Although be careful, as anything as small as a whitespace is enough to make :empty non valid:


h3 span:empty {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
<h3>
    <span>Title</span>
    <span></span>
</h3>

<h3>
    <span>Title</span>
    <span> </span>
</h3>

<h3>
    <span>Title</span>
    <span><a>link</a><a>link</a></span>
</h3>




Today I learned about the :empty CSS pseudo-class thanks to Sigurd!

You could use has() for that:


h3>span+span:not(:has(a))::after {
    border: solid 1px transparent;
    content: '\2199';
    display: inline-block;
    color: gray;
}
<h3>
    <span>Title</span>
    <span></span>
</h3>

<h3>
    <span>Title</span>
    <span><a>link</a><a>link</a></span>
</h3>




Thanks. I like that. A little more targeted than :not(:has(*)).
